# TelephonyManager Android

Tags: android, serial

Gostaria de saber o que é retornado no android na Classe `TelephonyManager` quando chamo o método `getDeviceId`, o dispositivo não possui chip. Pois preciso de um identificador para o dispositivo e pensei em usar o IMEI, porém não tenho um dispositivo sem CHIP para testar o retorno dessa informação. Segue abaixo o código.

```
TelephonyManager tManager =  (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId(); //Serial do dispositivo android
```

Comment: Hiago, se não me engano o IMEI não depende do telefone ter chip ou não, depende apenas dos slots. Outra alternativa é usar o ANDROID_ID, que é gerado no primeiro boot de qualquer dispositivo Android, inclusive tablets. Dê uma olhada na documentação do [ANDROID_ID](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

Comment: Ok, Obrigado pela atenção.